# Castle Windsor Multiple Implementation For Same Inteface in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, castle

If I have multiple implementations of the same interface eg: `IRule`, how would I be able to resolve it in my controller?

```
private readonly IRule[] _rules;

public HomeController(IRule[] rules)
{
    _rules = rules;
}

public RunRules() 
{
    foreach (IRule rule in rules)
        rule.RunRule();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into an issue where I wanted to set up my controller to pull in a collection of rules, but didn't want to list each rule by itself so I had an array of `IRule[]` that I set up.

Controller:

```
private readonly IRule[] _rules;

public HomeController(IRule[] rules)
{            
     _rules = rules;
}
```

Installer:

Set up castle windsor installer.

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.Register(Component.For<IRule>().ImplementedBy<ValidateNPIRule>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IRule>().ImplementedBy<ValidateZipRule>());
}
```

The important part was the line to `.AddSubResolver` 
Adding in the `CollectionResolver` was what I needed for the installer to resolve all of my rules at once and I could pull them in an array.

Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

    container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel, true));
    container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
}
```

Comment: So, is this part of your problem or a solution?

Comment: That's the answer.

Comment: This causes an exception stating that the component has already been registered

Comment: That's the exact code I used for our application without an error.  Register the same component, but I implemented 2 different classes, there is also another option that you can just implement it all in one line, so no matter what class implements from the IRule you won't have to remember to add it to the Install function.  I'll post that when I get my hands on that code.